# Cannot parse JSON - android

Tags: android, json

I'm new to android, I can't understand why am I getting this exception when trying to parse JSON. Please help, or suggest any alternative.

Json File containing all countries with their cities: 
[**citiesjson.txt**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ar81063b6imi3lx/citiesjson.txt?dl=0)

A sample of above file is:

```
{"China":["Guangzhou","Fuzhou","Beijing","Baotou","Hohhot","Guiyang","Yinchuan","Nanjing","Changzhou","Chuzhou","Jiaoyun","Guizhoumanzuxiang","Qingzhen","Changde","Xianning","Jiaozhou","Weifang","Tai'an","Luoxi","Guoji","Guangdong","Sijiqing","Huzhou","Panjin Shi","Daqing","Jilin City","Lianyungang","Yancheng","Yuehu","Kunshan","Taicang","Lianshui","Nantong","Jiaotong","Changshu City","Xingxiangcun","Jinsha","Jiangyan","Chaigoubu","Ma'anshan","Huainan","Haibei","Shenlong","Nangxian","Rongsheng","Changfeng","Chengqiao","Jiafu","Shenzhou","Shantou","Qingyuan","Gyari","Xinshijie","Zhaoqing","Zhanjiang","Kuicheng","Taoyuan","Jincheng","Caishen","Shiyan","Liaoyang","Xingtai","Wenchang","Wanning","Qionghai","Huilongba","Dingcheng","Baodian","Wuzhishan","Chengmai","Yinggen","Ledong","Lincheng","Baisha","Changjiang","Dongfang","Changjian","Jinmao","Yangpu","Baipo","Jiefang","Danzhou","Lingshui","Haidian","Sanya","Rongjiang","Longyan","Jinghe","Zhangjiakou","Renqiu","Yaocheng","Kaifeng","Hebi","Jiaozuo","Pingdingshan","Anshan","Dandong","Haitang","Tongchuan","Ankang","Guozhen","Shangluo","Yulong","Haixing","Sanjiaocheng","Pinghu","Jinling","Fengming","Tongxiang","Puyuan","Dingqiao","Yanjiang","Wutong","Pingchuan","Dushu","Nanxun","Wuxing","Yangzhou","Hongyuan","Anji","Shangying","Deqing","Digang","Sanguan","Yuantong","Changxin","Huating","Putuoshan","Jinyuan","Dinghai","Xiangnan","Putuo","Xintian","Donghuxu","Zhuji","Jingcheng","Jiangtian","Xingchang","Jindou","Xinchang","Baiyun","Qianqing","Tianchang","Tianchi","Luzhou","Qinjiang","Tianzhu","Mingdu","Shenjiamen","Longshan","Dengbu","Xiushan","Daizhong","Longteng","Beiyuan","Taili","Choucheng","Lucheng","Chengxiang","Dongying","Gangcun","Sailing","Shifan","Yaohua","Jingyuan","Fengtai","Gaocheng","Gu'an","Shuangshipu","Li'ao","Xi'ao","Tang Xian","Tara","Li'an","Hu'an","Datang","Tumu","Shuyi","Gaoxin","Boâ€™ao","Baocheng","Haifu","Xiuying","Xuanzhou","Gongjiang","Huayuji","Qu'an","Fuhao","Weiyang","Laohekou","Nanshan","Chen Xian","Siting","Wuhou","Jiâ€™an","Fuxin","Xiqu","Wangluo","Erqi","Donghong","Gaobeidian","Lianhua","Chenzhou","Dajie","Chenghua","Dongfeng","Zhu'ang","Maji","Songling","Chum","Cenyang","Hanshan","Xiaomi","Luohu","Hainan","Guangxi","Changle","Linfen","Yuanping","Jiazhuang","Heibei","Liaocheng","Huaihua","Rizhao","Fuzhou","Duyun","Tianshui","Guli","Jinhai","Chaoyang","Taixing","Fengxiang","Jinpan","Yizheng","Yunfu","Xinhui","Wenlan","Tieli","Taihe","Liuzhou","Hechi","Yunyang","Zhuxi Chengguanzhen","Heze","Shiqiaopu","Jiangbei","Shanzhuang","Danyang","Huai'an","Yantan","Guangchang","Xiguan","Xigu","Anying","Xiangtong","Guixi","Xidian","Pingliang","Pinghu","Changhe","Yangshan","Suji","Baizhang","Shuangxi","Yanming","Yiqiao","Xinxing","Dabao","Sanyuanpu","Gaobu","Linghu","Qingtong","Shuanglin","Dampu","Qi'an","Gouzhuang","Changsheng","Qianyu","Datong","Sandu","Anjiang","Huangjue","Name","Linqi","Zhanghe","Zheshang","Huadian","Kangcun","Zhangshan","Shouchang","Qiantan","Hongpan","Lin'an","Dingzhou","Jiuzong","Yuting","Guali","Jianci","Kaiyun","Chunhua","Hongwei","Shuguang","Diankou","Lidong","Fengqing","Fengqiao","Fengqi","Rongle","Huangzhai","Wuning","Yahao","Jifeng","Ancheng","Shangfang","Jiahu","Jinpu","Potang","Shangjiang","Xingqiao","Doujiang","Nyingchi County","Yangxunqiao","Chadianzi","Zhongyicun","Jialing","Jianxing","Xichong","Sanyi","Hongyan","Base","Yongxing","Nanhe","Naxi Yaozuxiang","Dongxing","Rongxian","Jinghong","Ning'er","Zhuozhou","Luquan","Li'an","Suqian","Dabu","Luoyang","Feiyun"],"Japan":["Tokyo",
```

My code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

throws exception
where **jsonString** = [image]

And the exception is:

```html
02-08 11:29:45.239      558-589/? E/SWIPE﹕ clear()
02-08 11:29:45.239      558-589/? D/SWIPE﹕ Check swipe down for x/y: 249.0 / 173.0
02-08 11:29:45.279      558-589/? D/SWIPE﹕ touch up event 249.0 173.0
02-08 11:29:45.279      558-589/? D/SWIPE﹕ send replay touch down event
02-08 11:29:45.329    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/BYD_Flex﹕ getValue() name = @NOKIAFLEX@packageNeedData
02-08 11:29:45.509    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/BYD_Flex﹕ getValue() readFlexFromXml = TypedValue{t=0x0/d=0x0}
02-08 11:29:45.509    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/BYD_Flex﹕ getValue() name = @NOKIAFLEX@setDataUsageReminder
02-08 11:29:45.679    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/BYD_Flex﹕ getValue() readFlexFromXml = TypedValue{t=0x0/d=0x0}
02-08 11:29:45.719    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11351: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
02-08 11:29:45.719    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11357: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
02-08 11:29:45.729    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9043: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
02-08 11:29:45.769    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11354: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
02-08 11:29:45.779    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 368: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-08 11:29:45.779    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 390: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-08 11:29:45.869      701-701/? D/Swype﹕ [IME] onStartInput(): false
02-08 11:29:45.919    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 295K, 7% free 8369K/8903K, paused 13ms+13ms, total 43ms
02-08 11:29:46.169    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 133K, 7% free 8542K/9095K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-08 11:29:46.199    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 75K, 8% free 8575K/9223K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-08 11:29:46.299    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 108K, 9% free 8872K/9671K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 57ms
02-08 11:29:46.359    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 162K, 10% free 8710K/9671K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
02-08 11:29:46.439    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 243K, 9% free 8831K/9671K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-08 11:29:46.479    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 9378K/10247K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 37ms
02-08 11:29:46.619    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 365K, 13% free 9014K/10247K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-08 11:29:46.649    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 9834K/11079K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 27ms
02-08 11:29:46.819    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 547K, 17% free 9287K/11079K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-08 11:29:46.859    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 15% free 10518K/12359K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 38ms
02-08 11:29:47.129    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 821K, 22% free 9697K/12359K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
02-08 11:29:47.169    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 19% free 11543K/14215K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 27ms
02-08 11:29:47.559    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1232K, 28% free 10313K/14215K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-08 11:29:47.599    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 13081K/14215K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 35ms
02-08 11:29:47.759    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1846K, 21% free 11235K/14215K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
02-08 11:29:47.789    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 7% free 13320K/14215K, paused 15ms+2ms, total 31ms
02-08 11:29:47.789    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
02-08 11:29:47.799    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2768K, 26% free 10551K/14215K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-08 11:29:47.839    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 12636K/14215K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 36ms
02-08 11:29:47.839    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
02-08 11:29:47.859    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 12636K/14215K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
02-08 11:29:47.899    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 10% free 15762K/17351K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 28ms
02-08 11:29:47.899    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
02-08 11:29:47.909    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2084K, 22% free 13678K/17351K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-08 11:29:47.939    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 10% free 15762K/17351K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 27ms
02-08 11:29:47.939    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
02-08 11:29:47.959    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 15762K/17351K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-08 11:29:48.029    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 9% free 17864K/19463K, paused 12ms+29ms, total 64ms
02-08 11:29:50.209    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 8013K, 42% free 11804K/20039K, paused 12ms+27ms, total 90ms
02-08 11:29:51.559    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 409K, 38% free 12555K/20039K, paused 12ms+21ms, total 86ms
02-08 11:29:53.179    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 484K, 33% free 13488K/20039K, paused 13ms+23ms, total 108ms
02-08 11:29:55.189    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 601K, 27% free 14633K/20039K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 129ms
02-08 11:29:57.459    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 675K, 21% free 15935K/20039K, paused 13ms+24ms, total 159ms
02-08 11:29:59.839    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 661K, 15% free 17211K/20039K, paused 12ms+31ms, total 179ms
02-08 11:29:59.989      558-588/? W/PowerManager﹕ accept Wake require,start process. the mTag is:AlarmManager, the mFlags is:1
02-08 11:30:00.019      558-575/? W/PowerManager﹕ accept Wake release,start process. the mTag is:AlarmManager, the mFlags is:1
02-08 11:30:01.639      558-588/? W/PowerManager﹕ accept Wake require,start process. the mTag is:AlarmManager, the mFlags is:1
02-08 11:30:01.649      558-707/? D/NtpTrustedTime﹕ forceRefresh() from cache miss
02-08 11:30:01.649      558-575/? W/PowerManager﹕ accept Wake release,start process. the mTag is:AlarmManager, the mFlags is:1
02-08 11:30:01.649      558-707/? D/SntpClient﹕ request time failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "2.android.pool.ntp.org": No address associated with hostname
02-08 11:30:01.649      558-707/? W/ThrottleService﹕ unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
02-08 11:30:08.389    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1280K, 12% free 17822K/20039K, paused 71ms, total 71ms
02-08 11:30:13.059    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 649K, 10% free 18145K/20039K, paused 72ms, total 72ms
02-08 11:30:19.949    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 970K, 14% free 18630K/21511K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
02-08 11:30:20.069    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 13% free 20813K/23751K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 107ms
02-08 11:30:22.949      558-584/? D/BatteryService﹕ level:99 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 4196 temperature: 410 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17303055 invalid charger:0
02-08 11:30:28.729    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1457K, 19% free 19358K/23751K, paused 72ms, total 72ms
02-08 11:30:28.819    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 18% free 21442K/25863K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 86ms
02-08 11:30:28.819    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 64ms
02-08 11:30:28.889    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 18% free 21442K/25863K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
02-08 11:30:28.999    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 16% free 23527K/27975K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 98ms
02-08 11:30:28.999    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 81ms
02-08 11:30:29.069    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2182K, 24% free 21344K/27975K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
02-08 11:30:29.169    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2084K, 20% free 22386K/27975K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 97ms
02-08 11:30:29.169    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 84ms
02-08 11:30:29.249    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2084K, 28% free 20302K/27975K, paused 81ms, total 81ms
02-08 11:30:29.339    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 20% free 22387K/27975K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 86ms
02-08 11:30:29.339    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 73ms
02-08 11:30:29.409    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3126K, 32% free 19260K/27975K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
02-08 11:30:29.499    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 24% free 21344K/27975K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 86ms
02-08 11:30:29.499    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 74ms
02-08 11:30:29.579    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 24% free 21344K/27975K, paused 83ms, total 83ms
02-08 11:30:29.679    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 17% free 23429K/27975K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 98ms
02-08 11:30:30.579    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2084K, 24% free 21344K/27975K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
02-08 11:30:30.679    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 22% free 24471K/31111K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 97ms
02-08 11:30:31.579    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2084K, 29% free 22386K/31111K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
02-08 11:30:31.619    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value {"Belarus":["Minsk","Mogilev","Brest","Vitebsk","Dvor-Gomel'","Hrodna","Navapolatsk","Lida","Horki","Borisov","Lyakhovichi","Radoshkovichi","Polatsk","Orsha","Valer'yanovo","Baranovichi","Mazyr","Lyaskavichy","Zhodzina","Zaslawye","Lahoysk","Shklow","Mozyr'","Dzyarzhynsk","Pinsk"],"":[""],"Philippines":["Manila","Ayala","Bayan","Roosevelt","Blumentritt","Cardona","Pasong Tamo","Valenzuela","Caloocan City","Taytay","Quezon City","Las Pinas","Makati City","Marikina City","San Juan","Pasig","Paranaque City","Muntinlupa","Salinas","Poblacion","Roxas City","Puerto Princesa City","Pasay","Caloocan","Buting","Lipa City","Taguig","Baguio City","San Pablo City","San Mateo","Rizal","Dasmarinas","Sucat","Sampaloc","Marilag","Angeles City","Mandaluyong City","Malabon","Rodriguez","Fairview","Angeles City","Davao City","Iligan","Cagayan de Oro","Tagum","Butuan","Mawab","Ozamiz City","Bacoor","Cavite City","Carmona","Imus","Tacurong","Pateros","Dumaguete","Carolinas","San Pedro","General Santos","Malolos","Cebu City","Malate","New Manila","Antipolo","Villanueva","Concepcion","Koronadal","Pandi","West","Lucena City","Balayan","Laguna","Calamba","Subic","Bonifacio","Quezon","Lapu-Lapu City","Tagaytay","San Carlos City","San Jose","Asia","Subic","Libis","Palma Gil","Fernandez","Kalibo","Santos","Vargas","Novaliches","Plaza","San Antonio","Philippine","Rizal","Alabang","Legaspi","Laguna","Summit","Bates","Bagumbayan","Salcedo","Batis","Cubao","Binondo","Balabag","General","Guagua","Liberty","Tandang Sora","Capitol","Naga City","Binangonan","San Francisco","Mabalacat","Pikit","Antipolo","Imus","Tarlac City","Batangas","Calapan","Binan","Cabuyao","Hilongos","Mandaue City","Tanza","Caloocan","Silang","Malabon","Navotas","Angat","Navotas","Bulacan","Laoag","Bocaue","Dagupan","Calasiao","Dingras","Cainta","Iloilo City","Iloilo City","Tagbilaran City","Balanga","Pulilan","Olongapo City","Marilao","San Jose","San Fernando","Plaridel","Baliuag","Cabanatuan City","Bataan","Navotas","San Fernando","Meycauayan","Manila","Kawit","Bacolod City","Angono","Los Banos","Paete","Santa Rosa","Calamba City","Santa Cruz","Pangil","Canlubang","Tayabas","Pagsanjan","Zamboanga City","Talisay City","Mandaue City","Ugong Norte","Luna","Olongapo City","Tanauan","Cabatuan","Pasig","West Triangle","Pias","San Pedro","Dipolog City","Victorias City","Zamboanga City","Subic","Abucay","Samal","Orion","Arayat","Boac","Siniloan","San Agustin","Cotabato City","Veronica","Masbate","Bool","Tacloban City","Danao","Rosario West","Taft","Sulo","Centre","Santo","Pagasinan","Cafe","Leyte","Interior","Pagadian","Molave","Palo","Mamungan","Hagonoy","Paul","Bagong Nayon","Mauban","La Trinidad","Apalit","Mariveles","General Trias","Cabugao","Province of Pangasinan","Urdaneta","Alaminos","Malasiqui","Bay","Balungao","Amadeo","Macabebe","Del Monte","Limay","Calbayog City","Real","Tanay","Kapatagan","Trece Martires City","Lamitan","Bagac","Jagna","Obando","Balagtas","Kidapawan","Pampanga","Naga","Diliman Primero","Baao","Cauayan","Pacita","Central","Rosales","Bulacan","Roque","Silang","La Salette","San Miguel","Baclaran","Marcos","Suyo","Maquiling","Plaridel","Los Martires","Acacia","Minalin","Salle","Agusan Pequeno","Gitagum","Pardo","Gallego","Gloria","Nueva","Upper Bicutan","Wines","Vito","La Union","Poblacion, San Felipe","Lawis","Toledo City","Concepcion","Digos","Cogan","Calinan","Mindanaw","Dagupan","Barbar","Mangaldan","San Fabian","Alcala","Bautista","Aquino","Ilog","Manaoag","Tayug","Luzon","San Miguel","Victory","Sta Cruz","Sultan Kudarat","Magsaysay","Dapitan","Mangrove","Tanauan","Alfonso","Island Park","Maria","Tigbauan","Campus","Valencia","Occidental","Panabo","Munoz East","Aguilar","Fortuna","Matandang Balara","Osmena","Leon","Balamban","Cotabato City","Cavinti","Alitagtag","Trinidad","Lilio","Carlos","Vigan","Domingo","Candon","Norte","Oara","Alaminos","Calaca","Padre Garcia","Bauan","Cagayan","Tuguegarao City","Ilagan","Santiago","Llanera","China","Ramon","Feliciano","Marina","Cruz","Ventura","Tambo","Tejer
02-08 11:30:31.629    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
02-08 11:30:31.629    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
02-08 11:30:31.629    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
02-08 11:30:31.629    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at ui.CreateNewTeamActivity.populateCitySpinner(CreateNewTeamActivity.java:66)
02-08 11:30:31.629    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at ui.CreateNewTeamActivity.populateSpinners(CreateNewTeamActivity.java:56)
02-08 11:30:31.629    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at ui.CreateNewTeamActivity.onCreate(CreateNewTeamActivity.java:50)
02-08 11:30:31.639    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5181)
02-08 11:30:31.639    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-08 11:30:31.639    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
02-08 11:30:31.639    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1908)
02-08 11:30:31.639    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
02-08 11:30:31.639    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
02-08 11:30:31.639    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)
02-08 11:30:31.649    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
02-08 11:30:31.649    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
02-08 11:30:31.649    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:548)
02-08 11:30:31.649    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
02-08 11:30:31.649    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16987)
02-08 11:30:31.649    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-08 11:30:31.659    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 11:30:31.659    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 11:30:31.659    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4807)
02-08 11:30:31.659    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 11:30:31.659    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 11:30:31.659    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
02-08 11:30:31.669    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559)
02-08 11:30:31.669    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 11:30:31.909    1228-1234/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ CPU[1] offline
02-08 11:30:32.669    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 22% free 24480K/31111K, paused 12ms+978ms, total 1081ms
02-08 11:30:32.739    3385-3385/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8730K, 50% free 15749K/31111K, paused 74ms, total 74ms
02-08 11:30:32.779    3385-3387/com.zerotech.cricketscoring.cricketscoring D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 43% free 17834K/31111K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 33ms
02-08 11:30:33.139    1228-1234/? E/ThermalDaemon﹕ CPU[1] offline
02-08 11:30:38.299      558-586/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ qyq:Set brightness target =  7    currentValue = 255
02-08 11:30:38.299      558-585/? E/lights﹕ debug:set_light_backlight    254
02-08 11:30:38.299      558-586/? D/PowerManagerService﹕ qyq:Set brightness target =  255    currentValue = 255
```

And the exception snapshot is:
[image]

Or if someone has the all countries with their cities 'string-array', then that would be another solution to my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Still haven't downvoted... Make your json more accesible. Put a part of it in your question... enough to explain the format... A dropbox link of the most-important part is not a good way to ask a question... All I can know... you may have uploaded a malware and I am `not downloading` that... nor should anyone else.

Comment: I've udpated, actually the file was very big, showing error here. But I've updated the post Sir.

Comment: What I meant is... enough to explain the format... Is this Something like `{ "country1" : [ "city11", "city12, "city12" ], "country2": [ "city21", "city22" ]  }`.. ?

Comment: The JSON string represents an object, not an array. Using `new JSONObject(jsonString)` could work better.

Comment: I hope @Henry solved your problem.

Comment: When I changed that to JSONObject, I got this exception:
`org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved because of you guys, I'm thankful to Henry and Haider Saddique.

There were two problems:

1) Rather than

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

I must use:

`JSONObject jsonArray = new JSONObject(jsonString);`

Thanks to Henry. But only changing this causes type mismatch exception, so follow 2nd point.

2) There were many "" in my .json
So I removed all objects with empty string in my .json file.

Thanks to Haider Saddique.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json have a list of `JSONObject(s)` and each `JSONObject` have a `JSONArray` as value.

So to parse it, you need to loop through `JSONObject(s)` keys (China, Japan...) and then get the `JSONArray` for each one:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(yourJson);
Iterator<String> itr = jObj.keys(); // get the keys list (countries name)

while(itr.hasNext()) { // loop the list of countries
   String countryName = itr.next(); // get the next key (a new country name)
   JSONArray cytiesArray = jObj.getJSONArray(countryName);// get cities for the current country
}
```